# ¿Se pueden almacenar operación aritméticas en variables de js?

Tags: javascript, html, script

estoy empezando con js y estoy haciendo una calculadora. Necesito almacenar las operaciones en un array y que si ponga esto funcione.

```
<i>var num1 = 2;<br>
var num2 = 5;<br>
var operation = "*";<br>
var solution = num1 + operation + num2;<br>

// solution = 10.</i>
```

Comment: En solution, en realidad habrían unos botones almacenando la operacion en una variable, que posteriormente se pondría en operation[0]. Y lo necesito hacer así por si introduce más de una operación a la vez. Si hay otra manera de hacerlo estoy habierto a sugerencias.

Comment: Puede construir una función concatenando el `return`  y ejecutarla con **()** , ejemplo :  `console.log(new Function('return ' + solution)());`

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es obtener el resultado de la expresión almacenada en el String.

Podrías utilizar la función **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval)** para evaluar tu expresión:

```js
var num1 = 2;
var num2 = 5;
var operation = "*";
var solution = num1 + operation + num2;

console.log(eval(solution));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco Romero funcionó.

Comment: @user733419 si la respuesta solucionó su pregunta, considere aceptarla.